# How to convert .nm2 to .osm

Tags: openstreetmap

How can I convert `Navitel` map format `.nm2` to default Open Street Map format `.osm`?
I know the `osmconverter` but it doesn't provide this kind of functionality.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What other formats can `.nm2` be converted to?

Comment: @scai my goal is use this map (exactly this), in my app, the final format will be .map, it used for mapsforge